# SQLplus script from file with bash substitutions

Tags: bash, sqlplus, substitution

I am running a bash script that includes a here document, which calls SQLPLUS.  This includes a .sql script to perform several grants.  It works correctly without the substitution.

I want to be able to substitute in a bash variable into the grant statements.  Is that possible?

This is a snippet from the bash script

```
CREDLINE=ownusr/ownpass
GRANT2DO=foo.sql
PASSPROC=bar    <=== this is what I want to pass
sqlplus << EOQ11
$CREDLINE@chaos01
@$GRANT2DO
quit
EOQ11
```

This is a snippet from the foo.sql

```
grant execute on $PASSPROC to user86;
grant execute on $PASSPROC to user99;
```

I have tried several variations on $VAR and &1, but none has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the sql-script with the value of what you want to pass

from sqlplus execute the script:

```
@foo.sql bar
```

in foo.sql use:

```
grant execute on &1 to usr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your script *create* `.sql` file instead of having it *replace existing* one. Then pass it to `sqlplus` like you already do.

To make the script readable, you can use so-called "here documents" syntax, which is described [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and which you are seemingly already familiar with.

If you insist on doing actual substitution, you could copy the template `.sql` to some temporary file and run `sed -i` on it with proper arguments to replace the variables. That, however, is much more complicated than the approach above.